# Пройти авторизацию на сайте с помощью python

Tags: html, python, парсер, аутентификация

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baSEc.png)http://rozklad.kpi.ua/Schedules/ScheduleGroupSelection.aspx
Есть такой сайт, на этой странице нужно авторизоваться, выбрав номер группы. 
Я не могу понять, как формируется ссылка, и какой атрибут принимает значение этой группы.Поэтому не могу сформировать адекватный пост запрос, потому что не могу понять что мне передавать в поле data.Подставлял множество атрибутов,но ничего не происходит. :(

```
import requests
url = 'http://rozklad.kpi.ua/Schedules/ScheduleGroupSelection.aspx'
data = {'ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$txtboxGroup': 'ІО-65'}
s = requests.session()
z = s.post(url, data)
```

[[image: Вы про эти hidden??]]
Вы про эти hidden??

Comment: Ого, Киевский политех, респект! открывайте в chrome F12 дальше Elements, ищите `<form ... >`, там много скрытых(hidden) полей и группа(`ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$txtboxGroup`), так же вас интересует поле action  и method. Копайте в этом направлении.

Comment: @LexHobbit 
Я послал вот такой пост запрос z = s.post(url, data = {'ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$txtboxGroup': 'ІО-65'}). Результат нулевой. Тоесть с другими сайтами у меня авторизация проходит успешно. Здесь же то ли это не тот елемент, который принимает номер группы, то ли я не понимаю чего-то. ((

Comment: hidden поля тоже надо посылать, таким образом у вас не полный словарь в data. То что post используете, молодец. А вот какой url  у вас тоже не известно. Дополните вопрос кодом

Comment: @LexHobbit дополнил  вопрос,